# Export data to another Google sheet and use it as database

Tags: google-sheets

Hope you are doing great!

I made a code that sends data from "sheet1" to "sheet2" writhing same spreadsheet, but what about sending the data to another Workbook? I am writing my code below for your reference. I would appreciate if you could help me out in this.

Below is the code that is not working and giving me error ( Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet):-

```
  function ALFA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 'var ss2 =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1E3CWWohirN4DD_f_23WWBElYrhqnAs_27crrxowFjFA");
  var sheetTwo = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("KEY WORK");
  var sheetThree = ss.getSheetByName("DATABASE");
  var data = sheetOne.getDataRange().getValues();
  var columnCount = data[0].length
  var firstCol = sheetOne.getRange("E2:E50");
  var matchValue = "LIVE";
  var Discon = "DISCONTINUED";
  var j = sheetTwo.getLastRow() + 1;
  var he = "1";

  for (var i = 0; i < firstCol.getValues().length; ++i) 
  {
    if (firstCol.getValues()[i][0] === matchValue || firstCol.getValues()[i][0] === Discon) 
 {
  sheetOne.getRange(i+2,1,1,columnCount).copyTo(sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount),        
  {contentsOnly:true});
  sheetTwo.getRange(j,6,1,1).setValue(he);
  sheetOne.deleteRow(i+2);
  i = i - 1;
  j = j + 1;
}
}

}
```

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!!

spreadSheet A (source sheet):-

```
  NAME      roll number     class     section    Status
 ------    -------------   -------    -------    -------
 Shallu         21           12          A         QC
 rahulo         21           11          B         LIVE
 beta12         21           11          A         QC
 alfa12         21           12          C         DISCONTINUE
 rotate         21           10          A         QC
 SHUBHAM        21           12          B         QC
```

expected result in Spread sheet B (Target Sheet)

```
 rahulo         21           11          B         LIVE
 alfa12         21           12          C         DISCONTINUE
```

Comment: why is no one helping out?

Comment: why are you calling copyTo(...) if you are already setting the values in the next statement? One of both should be enough and I think sheets is giving you the error because copyTo only works in one spreadsheet...

Comment: @jvdh Thanks for your reply! But the value I am calling in the next statement is another value so kindly suggest a new solution.

Comment: how do I copy this whole information "sheetOne.getRange(i+2,1,1,columnCount)" to sheetTwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems with your code, but the main one is that you try to have 2 active spreadsheets at the same time (you can only have one).

I tried to rewrite your function and for my [dummy spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ndYks_xK7MXUcy2JRfo-hZLh1fFwis76MPyX42T_Gso/edit#gid=0) it does the trick. If you have problems, give us more information about what and how you are trying to copy and we can help you more.

```
function main() {

  alfa("1OrIcgi6es7l0wZNTTmhJeoTt2eX4Yn1vCXlxYEAXuiw", "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "A2:E50")

}

function alfa(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName, range) {
  var matchValue = "LIVE";
  var Discon = "DISCONTINUED";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);

  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var counter = 0;

  // delete rows with LIVE/DISCONTINUED in source sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][4] != matchValue && data[i][4] != Discon) {
      newData.push([]);
      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        newData[counter].push(data[i][j]);
      }
      counter += 1;
    }

  }
  sourceSheet.getRange(range).clear();
  sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)
             .setValues(newData);

  // copy data
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  var targetValues = [];
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][4] == matchValue || data[i][4] == Discon) {
      targetValues.push([]);
      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        targetValues[counter].push(data[i][j]);
      }
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  //get last row
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();

  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length)
             .setValues(targetValues);

}
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well. What I was trying to do was search the text "Live" or "Discontinue" in a range "E2:E50" of a google spreadsheet(A) if the match found then it should copy the entire row to a different spreadsheet(B) in a sheet called "sheet1". Note it should delete the copied row from spreadsheet (A).

Comment: Ok I have got it now, And its working but with some difficulties. Some How This code is also deleting the first row.

Comment: oh yes, because I said  `sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);`
it should be getRange(2,...) - changed the code accordingly

Comment: wallaah it works great now. Thank you very much for your support. Hope many people will get benefited from your answer. Best Regards, Mask

Comment: Hello jvdh, if you are still active in this page then I need your help again.

Comment: is your question related? otherwise it would probably be best to create a new question.

Comment: Although Its related but I think it would require a new code line, basically I want to do the same thing like copy only the active row to a different spreadsheet. what do you suggest should I create another question?

Comment: Hello jvdh please find the new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475661/copy-only-active-row-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another)