# Copy only active row from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script to copy the active row of a sheet(TIME MACHINE) to another Google spreadsheet's sheet(Database). I also want to send "1" to the 13 row of the copied row. It would be great if anyone can guide me. The code given below only works to copy within the same spreadsheet.

```
function endTime() {

transfer("1E3CWWohirN4DD_f_23WWBElYrhqnAs_27crrxowFjFA", "TIME MACHINE", "TIME MACHINE2")

}

function transfer(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {

var d = new Date();
var offset = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
var h = d.getHours();
var h = h >= 13? h - 12: h;
h = h == 0? 12: h;
var m = m < 10? "0" + d.getMinutes(): d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
var last = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 1, 1, 14).getValues();
var time1 = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

sourceSheet.getRange(last, 28).setValue(time1);


var tamma = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 11).getValue();

// copy data
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
//get last row
var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
//write data
targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
//write "1" into column 13
targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 13, data.length, 1).setValue("1");
targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 11, data.length, 1).setValue(tamma);
}
```

Comment: do you mean the 13th column?

Comment: Oh yes! you are right. jvdh I tried using your previous code but its giving me errors.

Comment: ok, sorry, I have no idea what you are doing with this for-loop, because in the beginning you increment i and afterwards you decrement it. This means that i is always equal to 1.

Which begs the question, do you want to copy one row or multiple rows?

Comment: ok I have edited my question this might give you a clear Idea. what I am trying to do is copy only the active row to a different worksheet.

Comment: I don't think any loop is required but I have no idea how to copy only the single active row to a different sheet.

Comment: Hello jvdh, I have edited the code best as per my knowledge. Kindly have a look again.

Comment: what do you mean with the active row? the row that has been last edited? or the last row?

Comment: entire row of a slected cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code just needs a little reorganization and you need to get the right data from the source-sheet.

this should work:

```
function main() {

transfer("1mEluY-_K9oBvbxzASKn25YZ8BgF_naLl0XNitb4zIA8", "Sheet1", "Sheet1");

}
function transfer(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var last = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 1, 1, 14).getValues();

  // copy data
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  //get last row
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  //write data
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
           .setValues(data);
  //write "1" into column 13
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 13, data.length, 1)
           .setValue("1")

}
```

Comment: Hello jvdh, this code is giving error "range not found".

Comment: probably because you didn't insert any parameters. Added a main function to the code so its easier to see for you. Now just have to change the parameters (spreadsheet-key and sheet names).

Comment: Now it gives me "Exceeded maximum stack depth", any idea jvdh what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I researched a little bit in Google and found that this is due to recursion, I quote Google :- "There is small limitation in Google Apps Script during recursion. You can call only 1000 inherited functions. 
If your script call multiple times, you will get error:
Exceeded maximum stack depth ". However I dont think our code is doing such thing what do you suggest.

Comment: mh, it works for me. Can you try copy-pasting my code again? You only need to change the parameters of the transfer-call in main (i.e. the key and sheetnames). I'm guessing that your code is missing a curly brace that closes the main function. 
link to my spreadsheet1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SxYB1uL6EJfXHTEWc_FHM5rdY_3J9TR1y43NqDwVvGU/edit?usp=sharing
and spreadsheet 2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mEluY-_K9oBvbxzASKn25YZ8BgF_naLl0XNitb4zIA8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok jvdh I am editing my code and pasting exactly what my code looks like.

Comment: Kindly let me know if you see any issue with my code above. Please do not worry about the top section of my code, its just to calculate time and I suppose its not doing any harm to your code.

Comment: well as there is no real change in the bottom code it should work

Comment: I don't know what to do now its still showing the same error "Exceeded maximum stack depth"

Comment: Hold on I think I got the fault now, I have many other scripts and one of them has a function transfer(){}.

Comment: Ohh Yes Yes!!! that was the problem. I had another script which also had a declaration called function transfer(){}. this was the problem. I changed it and now its working fine. @jvdh you  have been such a supporter and the best guide who does not get irritated by questions. You are a good man. Thanks a lot dear!

Comment: happy to hear :). in future it might help if you'd isolate the critical parts of the code before asking the question:
a) you will get faster answers
b) you might solve the problem yourself by understanding your code better

Comment: My Bad! that was by mistake.